# How to check whether an item is present in an Ansible array?

Tags: ansible

Let's say I have the following example, storing all `git config` values in an Ansible variable:

```
- shell: git config --global --list
  register: git_config_list
```

Ansible stores the result of this command in the `git_config_list` variable, and one of the items is `stdout_lines`, containing the output of the command in an array of entries, e.g.

```
[
"user.name=Foo Bar",
"user.email=foo@example.com"
]
```

How can I check whether a certain value is already set, e.g. for verifying that `user.name` has a value?

Is there a way to call something like `contains` on the array, combined with a regular expression, allowing me to find the value I'm looking for? Or do I have to loop over the `stdout_lines` entries to find what I'm looking for?

An example on how to do something like this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In theory this should be possible by combining the filters [`match`](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_filters.html#other-useful-filters) and [`select`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#select). The latter returns only those list elements which pass another filter. Then you could test for the length of the result.

In theory. I just tested it and I can't get it to work. In general the `select` (as well as the `reject`) filter returns a string like `<generator object _select_or_reject at 0x10531bc80>` even with simple filters like the example from the docs with `odd`. Wasn't able to find a solution yet. Maybe you have more success.

Though you could simply `join` your list to a string and then search in the string with `match`. While it's ugly, it works.

```
git_config_list.stdout_lines | join("|") | match("user.name=[^|]+")
```

Comment: The string from `select` can be converted to a list with the list filter: `| list`

Answer (score 22):

Simple python `in` would do just fine, NOTE I use `stdout` instead of `stdout_lines`:

```
- debug: git_config_list contains user.name
  when: "'user.name=' in '{{git_config_list.stdout}}'"
```

All in all `ansible` is horrible for programming. Try to do as much as you can outside the playbook and write only the orchestration logic inside the playbook. Here are a few examples how you can do it using `--get` option of `git`.

```
- hosts: localhost
  tags: so
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
  - shell: git config --global --get user.name
    register: g
    changed_when: False
    failed_when: False
  - debug: msg="config has user.name"
    when: "0 == {{g.rc}}"

- hosts: localhost
  tags: so
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
  - name: assert user.name is set
    shell: git config --global --get user.name
    changed_when: False

# git config --global --unset user.name
# ansible pb.yml -t so
# git config --global --add user.name 'Kashyap Bhatt'
# ansible pb.yml -t so
```

Answer (score 5):

With select and match (extend answer of udondan):

```
git_config_list.stdout_lines | select('match', 'user\.name=.+') | list
```